# Is it possible to wrap a secret key with multiple public keys?

Tags: java, security

Is it possible to wrap a secret key with multiple public keys?

Imagine i get the one secret and multiple public keys from somewhere...
I wonder if i can wrap a secret key with multiple keys, because i would like multiple clients to have acess to that secret key. Should i wrap the secret key with one client public key at a time or wrap all at once?

Java code:

```
SecretKey secretKey = createSecretKey();
List<PublicKey> publicKeys = new ArryList<>();

for(String publicKey: publicKeys ) {

    Cipher cipher = getWrapCipher(publicKey, "RSA");
    byte[] wrappedSecretKey = wrapSecretKey(secretKey, cipher);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “cypher”? The word isn’t usually used as a verb (and when it is, it’s used in a way that doesn’t work here) …

Comment: i meant wrap, instead of cipher... Is it possible to wrap a Secret Key with multiple public keys?

Comment: Just copy the secret key and wrap/encrypt each key with the public key of one recipient/user. Make sure you are able to identify which wrapped key belongs to what public key or user.

Comment: i was thinking like that. but isn't possible to wrap all at once?

Comment: No you need to encrypt individually for each user. That is the way RSA works. Also encryption schemes like OpenPGP work this way: `The session key is encrypted using each recipient's public key.` https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880